# send String from one class to a activity

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, android-geofence

My app uses geofences to notify the user when the enter a location, a notification gets displayed when the user enters the location. 
what im trying to to is get the triggering geofences convert them to a string, then send them to another activity so that they can be displayed in a list view.
Ive watched tutorials online on how to makes list views and how to send data using intents but what im trying to do just doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT**
I'm starting the list view PageActivity using a intent with startActivity from another class the MainActivity.

**Goals**

If the user clicks on the notification from anywhere especially from outside the application it will open the app with the list view being filled with the geofence details. If the user opens the app just opens the app the from the launcher, then the same to happen. The list to be filled with any geofences that were triggered.

**GeofenceTransitionsIntentService Class:**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";



    /**
     * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
     */
    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents.
     * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
     *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()){
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the Transistion Type
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transisition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transistion details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );


            headsUpSmsNotifaction(geofenceTransitionDetails);


            Intent i = new Intent(this, listPageActivty.class);
            i.putExtra("intentKey",geofenceTransitionDetails);



            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else{
            // Log the error
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));

        }

    }


    /**
     * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
     *
     * @param context               The app context.
     * @param geofenceTransition    The ID of the geofence transition.
     * @param triggeringGeofences   The geofence(s) triggered.
     * @return                      The transition details formatted as String.
     */

    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(Context context, int geofenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }

        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);


        return  geofenceTransitionString + ": "  + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    /**
     * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
     * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
     */


    private void headsUpSmsNotifaction(String notificationDetails){

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, sendSmsReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,44,notificationIntent,0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mdfromat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:ss | dd/ MM / yyyy");
        String strDate = mdfromat.format(calendar.getTime());



        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{10,10,10})
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(strDate)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"send",notificationPendingIntent)

                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);


        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        //builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }



    /**
     * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
     *
     * @param transitionType    A transition type constant defined in Geofence
     * @return                  A String indicating the type of transition
     */

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }

    }
}
```

**listPageActivty Class:**

```
public class listPageActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] ListElements = new String[]{"Android","PHP"};
    String item = "one";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_page_activty);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

        final List<String> ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(listPageActivty.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListElementsArrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      Bundle bundleData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundleData == null){
            return;
        }

        String intentItem = bundleData.getString("intentKey");
        ListElementsArrayList.add(intentItem);


        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ListElementsArrayList.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Any Help would be Greatly Appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: I suggest starting a new Android project just to help you learn how to send data between activities.

Comment: I've done that , and I'm trying to use the code in that project and bring that code into this project

Comment: "what im trying to do just doesn't seem to work." What happens when you run your app? How does the actual result differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, listPageActivty.class);
i.putExtra("intentKey",geofenceTransitionDetails);
```

to this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, listPageActivty.class);
i.putExtra("intentKey",geofenceTransitionDetails);
this.startActivity(i);
```

I think you just left the `startActivity()`

And in the other `Activity` you get the value like this :

```
String GeoTransitionDetails = getIntent().getExtras().getString("intentKey");
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me :) it was because i hadnt the startActivity in the same intent i wanted to use. didnt think i needed it as i was using the startActivity in a different intent in a different class. thank you

Comment: Just another quick question, when i come out of the listPage Activity and then go back into it, the geofence list item that was there, disapears. do I have to do something to make it persist ?

Comment: Save it on a sharedpreferences if you want, tomorrow ill help you im going to sleep now sorry

Comment: Haven't had a chance to look at it since , will try shared preferences this evening. Have to do college work now. Thanks for the reply though , I'll get back to you later

Comment: If you face with some problems and ask a question on StackOverflow feel free to give me the link and I'll try to solve your doubt. :)

Comment: Ok great ! Thank you so much !  I will do

Answer (score 0):

You are nowhere starting `listPageActivty` activity

Replace

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, listPageActivty.class);
i.putExtra("intentKey",geofenceTransitionDetails);
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), listPageActivty.class);
i.putExtra("intentKey",geofenceTransitionDetails);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Comment: I'm using a intent in a different activity "Main Activity" to launch the listPage activity. Should I put the extras in from that activity ?

Comment: yes you should. There is no use of putting extra unless you call `startActivity`

Comment: So send the data to the main activity , then from their to the list view Page activity?

Comment: Why can't you start your activity from here only when you have the data.